# Counting vallues in a array with spelcial character

Tags: php, arrays, count

I want to count all the values (The name of the cities) in this array who have the character **t** before the last character in the string.

**ARRAY**

```
$cities_array = array(
"city1" => "Paris_t1",
"city2" => "Madrid_t1",
"city3" => "Amsterdam_t1",
"city4" => "London_i1",
"city5" => "Miami_i1",
"city6" => "Berlin_i1",
"city7" => "Brussels_i1",
"city8" => "Toronto_i1",
);
```

The results should be: **3** (Paris_t1 - Madrid_t1 - Amsterdam_t1)

I believe i have to combine:

```
array_count_values($cities_array)
```

and

```
substr($value, -2, 1) == "t"
```

I have tried, but I get only errors.

Comment: And what stops you from trying?

Comment: lol, do some coding , don't predict things :) ,  we will help you if you face any problems , when you implement the solution

Comment: I tried everything, but I get everytime errors.

Comment: @AnnaZina so post some code  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you what you want.

```
        $cities_array = array(
                "city1" => "Paris_t1",
                "city2" => "Madrid_t1",
                "city3" => "Amsterdam_t1",
                "city4" => "London_i1",
                "city5" => "Miami_i1",
                "city6" => "Berlin_i1",
                "city7" => "Brussels_i1",
                "city8" => "Toronto_i1",
                );
$count = 0;
$city_text = '';
foreach($cities_array as $city){
    if(substr($city, -2, 1) == "t"){
        $count++;
        $city_text .= $city . '-';
    }
}

echo $count. "(".rtrim($city_text,'-').")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
$cities_array = array(
    "city1" => "Paris_t1",
    "city2" => "Madrid_t1",
    "city3" => "Amsterdam_t1",
    "city4" => "London_i1",
    "city5" => "Miami_i1",
    "city6" => "Berlin_i1",
    "city7" => "Brussels_i1",
    "city8" => "Toronto_i1",
);

$filtered_array = array_filter($cities_array, function($val){
    return (strpos($val, 't', (strlen($val)-2)) !== false);
});

print_r($filtered_array);
```

**output:** - (you can implode array by - to get desired result)

```
Array
(
    [city1] => Paris_t1
    [city2] => Madrid_t1
    [city3] => Amsterdam_t1
)
```

In above solution in `strpos` third parameter `strlen($val)-2)` i.e. position will be searched from second last character of `$val`